Woman helps a girl who keeps falling to the ground
I want to know the title of a drama movie in which a woman helps a girl (not her daughter) to defend herself, because she doesn't react when falling to the ground and kids bully her because of this.
The movie possibly is 2000-2010 and I think it's from Europe. I don't know why, the name "intruder" comes to my mind when I think of this movie, but I couldn't find it...

I found it, it is an italian movie called La sconosciuta (The Unknown Woman in english) released in 2006.
In the movie, the protagonist is a retired ukrainian prostitute who escape to Italy and starts working as a maid. She befriends the adopted daughter of a family and helps her with her condition (cannot defend herself, so she hits badly against the ground when falling).
Wikipedia | IMDb
